# Usar delete em objetos alocados sem o new?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, gerenciamento-de-memória, delete

Olá, desde sempre até hoje nos meus projetos de c++ com Qt, sempre utilizei delete de objetos apenas quando eu os aloco dinamicamente com o operador *new*, porém no meu último projeto que estava relativamente grande, comecei a sentir uma diferença de performance conforme sua execução. O projeto em questão disparava imagens de uma câmera na tela, e com o tempo começou a ficar bem lerdo a sua sequencia de frames, mesmo dividindo seu processo em um QTimer. Como meu proeto possui muitas chamadas de objetos, comecei a pensar na questão de liberação de memória. 
A minha pergunta é, objetos alocados na stack, ou seja, um objeto não-dinâmico, deve ter sua memória liberada em algum momento?

Exemplo de objeto não-dinâmico que me refiro:

```
void MyClass::functionExample(){

    AnotherClass obj;
    obj.setData(1);

}
```

Normalmente utilizo delete ou chamo o destrutor da classe apenas para esta situação:

```
void MyClass::functionExample(){

    AnotherClass *obj = new AnotherClass();
    obj->setData(1);
}
```

No caso de objetos declarados como atributo *private* da minha classe, também devo liberar memórias desses objetos? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: O ideal é nem usar delete, é jogar o ponteiro dentro de um "smart pointer". Meu último grande projeto em C++ escaneava uso de "delete" e não construía se achasse um.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Observação importante**:
>
> Nesta resposta eu uso *livremente* a terminologia alocação "estática"
>   e "dinâmica" para me referir, respectivamente, à alocação de dados no
>   [stack e no heap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap). Eu chamo a alocação do stack de "estática"
>   porque ela é meio que imutável (é feita no início do programa), e a
>   alocação no heap de "dinâmica" porque o controle está mais diretamente
>   na mão do programador.
>
> O colega @Maniero, por exemplo, [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152765/c-usar-delete-em-objetos-alocados-sem-o-new/152776#comment315487_152770) muito bem o seguinte a
>   esse respeito:
>
> "Eu uso uma terminologia diferente, pra mim alocação estática é aquela
>   feita previamente e vale por toda a execução da aplicação, portanto
>   não precisa alocar. A alocação no stack, apensar do nome induzir a ser
>   algo estático por similaridade, não é uma alocação estática, ela é
>   automática. A alocação de todo o stack é estático, mas não os seus
>   objetos. Eu acho que a terminologia usada está errada e dá um
>   entendimento errado, pelo menos para quem entende do assunto. Pra quem
>   não entende vai até entender, mas o errado. Por isso a confusão."
>
> E o colega @José X. também [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152765/c-usar-delete-em-objetos-alocados-sem-o-new/152776?noredirect=1#comment315717_152770) muito bem a esse respeito:
>
> "Esse assunto vai longe...dêem uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation) e [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) (o
>   texto do SO aponta para o link da Wikipedia). Só queria dar mais um
>   exemplo: uma membro não-static e não-ponteiro de uma classe que é
>   instanciada no heap...apesar de não ser um ponteiro, esse membro na
>   verdade é alocado no heap, não no stack."
>
> Realmente, talvez o termo "alocação automática" seja mais apropriado
>   para não haver confusão. Fiz essa observação porque achei que ela era
>   importante, ainda que o foco da resposta não era esse necessariamente.

Os objetos alocados estaticamente (isto é, no stack) existem no escopo em que foram criados. Quando esse escopo termina, eles são automaticamente removidos pelo compilador. Assim, no seu código...

```
void MyClass::functionExample(){

    AnotherClass obj;
    obj.setData(1);

}
```

...a instância de `obj` vai existir apenas dentro do método `functionExample`. Quando esse método terminar, essa instância vai ser eliminada automaticamente (e o destrutor, se existir, vai ser invocado).

Diferentemente dos anteriores, objetos alocados dinamicamente (isto é, no heap) existem até que sejam *explicitamente* destruídos (pelo programador, em geral). Quando memória é alocada muitas vezes no heap e não é liberada por erro, ocorre o que se chama vazamento de memória (*memory leak*), o que causa mesmo uma gradual redução do desempenho do sistema pelo uso excessivo de recursos (ainda que não seja a exclusiva causa potencial de mal desempenho).

Assim, no seu código...

```
void MyClass::functionExample(){

    AnotherClass *obj = new AnotherClass();
    obj->setData(1);
}
```

Há um vazamento de memória. A variável `obj` é um ponteiro para uma instância de `AnotherClass`. Ela, por si só, é uma variável estaticamente alocada (no stack - não confunda com uma variável declarada como estática) e, portanto, existe somente dentro do escopo do método `functionExample`. Usando o operador `new`, você cria uma nova instância de `AnotherClass` (alocando memória para tal) e guarda o endereço dessa memória na variável `obj`. Quando o método `functionExample` termina, essa variável é eliminada, e como você não tem mais a referência do endereço que foi alocado não tem mais como liberar aquela memória que permanece "perdida" no heap até que todo o programa termine.

Note que o Qt tem alguns recursos para gerenciar automaticamente a memória de objetos herdados de `QObject`. Quando você cria uma widget, por exemplo, você pode informar como parâmetro o ponteiro para uma instância de outra widget (`QWidget*`) que será o "pai" desse objeto. Esse objeto pai irá automaticamente destruir todos os seus filhos quando ele próprio for eliminado.

Não sei se era o caso, já que você não citou, de a sua classe `AnotherClass` herdar de `QObject`, mas mesmo que fosse o vazamento ainda existe porque você não passou o tal parâmetro (geralmente `this` para indicar que o objeto atual é o pai daquele que está sendo criado).

Comment: Obrigado, esclareceu bem a minha dúvida. Você disse que uma instancia criada de um objeto como atributo de uma classe existirá enquanto a classe for utilizada. Em caso de multiplas chamadas de objetos, a liberação de memória se aplica neste caso? mesmo os atributos da classe não sendo dinamicos, é recomendavel que eu os libere da memória manualmente?

Comment: Eu disse isso sim, mas somente para os atributos que forem alocados de forma não-dinamica (isto é, não são ponteiros em que vc usou new). É, sim, a liberação de memória é igual, pois cada objeto terá o seu próprio escopo.

Comment: O termo alocação dinâmica realmente é muito usado. A estática não costumo ver. O *stack*  é estático, mas os objetos dentro dele que são as alocações que são referenciadas na resposta são feitas sob demanda. São dois conceitos de alocação. É verdade que eu já vi termos diferentes (acho que ativação, sei lá) para os objetos que são colocados no *stack*, mas todo mundo fala em alocar e é entendido. Tanto que o termo alocação automática significa que pode usar o que já está alocado (no sentido de reservado) na memória. A alocação é feita de forma simples, sem requisição.É confuso por ter 2 passos

Answer (score 2):

Você só deve usar `delete` para objetos alocados com `new`. Ponto.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, sabe me dizer se objetos alocados estáticamente precisam ser liberados da memória de alguma forma?

Comment: Yuri, a resposta é: não, não precisam. Objetos estáticos são eliminados quando saem do escopo (quando a função termina, por exemplo).

Comment: Obrigado! Uma ultima coisa,  mesmo se aplica caso o objeto não-dinâmico esteja como atributo da classe, e eu utilize ele posteriormente na minha classe?

Comment: Eu respondi. Dá uma olhada na resposta. E sim, um objeto estático que é atributo de uma classe vai existir enquanto a instância daquela classe (que o contém) existir.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira: seu comentário ficou confuso...um membro `static` de uma classe não depende da existência de nenhuma instância da classe;

Comment: Verdade José. Desculpe. Eu quis dizer de alocação estática. Não explicitamente declarado como `static`. Obrigado pelo aviso. :)

Comment: @Luiz Vieira Acho que ainda ficou confuso...imagino que por "alocação estática" você esteja querendo dizer que o objeto não foi criado no _heap_ (via new), mas minha impressão é que "alocação estática" não se aplica no caso

Comment: @JoséX. Que caso? Agora eu que não entendi o que vc quis dizer. PS: sim, por "alocação estática" foi isso mesmo que eu quis dizer.

Comment: Detalhe importante: `new`/ `delete` fazem a chamada do construtor/destrutor do objeto antes/depois de liberar a memória alocada por ele, enquanto as funções da família do `malloc()`/ `free()` não o fazem. -- pense no que pode acontecer se você misturar as duas coisas.

Comment: Eu uso uma terminologia diferente, pra mim alocação estática é aquela feita previamente e vale por toda a execução da aplicação, portanto não precisa liberar. A alocação no *stack*, apensar do nome induzir a ser algo estático por similaridade, não é uma alocação estática, ela é automática. A alocação de todo o *stack* é estático, mas não os seus objetos. Eu acho que a terminologia usada está errada e dá um entendimento errado, pelo menos para quem entende do assunto. Pra quem não entende vai até entender, mas o errado. Por isso a confusão.

Comment: Eu acho que não deve usar nem `delete`, nem `new`, ponto :D

Comment: @bigown "Na vida real" é praticamente impossível não usar new/delete em qualquer aplicação não trivial. Felizmente a partir do C++11 os smart pointers melhoraram bastante, e em consequência a necessidade de usar "raw" new/delete diminuiu bastante também. Mas os sistemas corporativos existentes **hoje**, cheios de new/delete, vão continuar a existir por muito tempo ainda...

Comment: @bigown Muito bem observado. Vou tomar a liberdade de copiar o comentário para o corpo da resposta, ok? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira só se pagar *royalties* :P E arrumei um lapso.

Comment: @bigown Tá, eu pago. rs

Comment: Esse assunto vai longe...dêem uma olhada aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation e aqui https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable (o texto do SO aponta para o link da Wikipedia). Só queria dar mais um exemplo: uma membro não-**static** e não-ponteiro de uma classe que é instanciada no heap...apesar de não ser um ponteiro, esse membro na verdade é alocado no heap, não no stack.

Comment: Muito bem observado, @JoséX. :) Eu também adicionei esse seu comentário no corpo da minha resposta, ok?